# menú calculadora, no logro hacer el menú

Tags: php

Quiero hacer un menú, donde pida por opción
0 salir
1 sumar
2 restar
3 multiplicar
4 dividir

la calculadora funciona sin problemas el problema es que no esta bien estructurada

una vez que la opción no sea salir, pedir datos y mostrar datos

si la opción es salir, salir del programa a través de página en blanco

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "es">
<head>
   <title>Calculadora</title>
   <meta charset = "UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

 Elija una opción:<br>
      0<input type="submit" name="operacion" value="salir"><br>
      1<input type="submit" name="operacion" value="+"><br> 
      2<input type="submit" name="operacion" value="-"><br>  
      3<input type="submit" name="operacion" value="*"><br>  
      4<input type="submit" name="operacion" value="/"><br>

<?php
 error_reporting(0);
 $op;
 $num1;
 $num2;

          $op= $_POST['operacion'];

          if($op!='salir'){
            //pedir datos
            echo " El resultado es: $c";
           }
            switch($op){

               case '+':
                  $c = $a + $b;
                  break;
               case '-':
                  $c = $a - $b;
                  break;
               case '*':
                  $c = $a*$b;
                  break;
               case '/':
                  $c = $a*$b;
                  break;
               case 'salir':
                  echo "¿Quieres salir? S/N?";
                  //pedir si o no
                  //si es no action pagina blanco


                  break;
            }







    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Gracias @NicolasOñate, he intentado mejorar la propuesta del problema, espero que esté bien así

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Esto es un ejercicio y tiene que ser así? ¿Cómo se ejecuta esto, cuál es el contexto? Realmente veo incómodo hacer una calculadora así. ¿Por qué no usas una interfaz gráfica con los números y las operaciones? O sea, una calculadora de verdad.

Comment: Tienes, cuanto menos, 3 fallos en tu código. No estás usando $num1 y $num 2, $a y $b no están definidas, solo están ahí puestas y listo. El switch nunca te va a decir nada, porque llamas a $c antes de que el switch pueda definir $c. Te voy a poner tu código en una respuesta bien estructurado y me cuentas que tal. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Para este tipo de casos yo aplicaría una lógica basada en un array, si observas, dentro del array se puede realizar la operación y devolver el valor. Incluso vamos a controlar que no ocurra un división por cero, lo cual resultaría en un crash de la aplicación. También se controla que el POST no esté vacío, devolviendo un mensaje en ese caso.

Aquí tendrás en `$res` el resultado final y lo puedes usar para conectarlo con la lógica del programa, sea seguir pidiendo datos, sea salir (tampoco se comprende bien cuál es el contexto en que debe funcionar tu calculadora, o por qué no usas una interfaz gráfica con los números y los botones para las operaciones).

```
$a=1; #Los datos $a y $b se tomarían dinámicamente de alguna parte, supongo
$b=3;
$op= !empty($_POST['operacion']) ? $_POST['operacion'] : 'none';
$allActions=array(
                    "+"=>$a+$b,
                    "-"=>$a-$b,
                    "*"=>$a*$b,
                    "/"=>$b==0 ? 0: $a/$b,
                    "salir"=>"¿Quieres salir? S/N",
                    "none"=>"No se postearon datos",
                 );
$res=$allActions[$op];
echo $res;
```

Comment: Interesante, pero será optimo realizar las 4 operaciones simultaneamente en vez de realizar sólo la solicitada?

Comment: @varTob interesante tu observación... Me parece que tratándose de dos variables concretas no habrá problema, aunque si por ejemplo el código es llamado en un bucle podría tener una carga adicional al realizar cuatro operaciones dentro del array. Volveré sobre el tema cuando me sea posible.

Answer (score 0):

No tienes porque hacer un input por cada opción. Podrías hacerlo mediante un `select`:

```
<select>
  <option value="salir">0</option>
  <option value="+">1</option>
  <option value="-">2</option>
  <option value="*">3</option>
  <option value="/">4</option>
</select>
```

Que queda mejor y acotas las posibles respuestas. O mediante un solo `<input type="number">`, pero en este caso tendrías que cambiar los case del `switch` por unos númericos.

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te pongo el código completo. Este archivo se ejecuta solo con una pequeña interfaz donde ingresar los números y seleccionar la operación. Además comprueba que estén todos los números y que no se divida entre 0, para evitar que se jorobe el programa. Me dices que tal te fue :D

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "es">
<head>
   <title>Calculadora</title>
   <meta charset = "UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST"> 
<p>Ingresa el primer número</p>
<input type="number" name="num1">
<p>Ingresa el segundo número</p>
<input type="number" name="num2">
 <p>Elija una opción:<p>
  <select name="operacion">
  <option value="salir">Salir</option>
  <option value="+">Sumar</option>
  <option value="-">Restar</option>
  <option value="*">Multiplicar</option>
  <option value="/">Dividir</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="Calcular">
</form>
<?php
 error_reporting(0);
 //Comprobamos que se reciba todo
if (isset($_POST['operacion']) && isset($_POST['num1']) && isset($_POST['num2'])) {
//comprobamos que no se divida entre 0  
if ($_POST['num2'] != 0) {

    $op= $_POST['operacion'];
    $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
    $num2= $_POST['num2'];
    //Si $op es distinto de salir operamos, si no decimos adios. No puse el código de redirección, es un simple header.
    if($op!='salir'){
        switch($op){

         case '+':
            $c = $num1 + $num2;
            echo " El resultado es: $c";
            break;
         case '-':
            $c = $num1 - $num2;
            echo " El resultado es: $c";
            break;
         case '*':
            $c = $num1 * $num2;
            echo " El resultado es: $c";
            break;
         case '/':
            $c = $num1 / $num2;
            echo " El resultado es: $c";
            break;
        }
     }else{
      echo "Aquí pones el header correspondiente para salir hacia la web en blanco o un mensaje.";
     }
  }else{
    //Se ha dividido entre 0, cancelamos operación
    echo "No seas mal@, no se puede dividir entre 0";
  }

}else{
  //NO se han ingresado todos los datos. 
  echo "Ingresa todos los números, por favor.";
}






?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias respuestas para lo que necesitas, te recomiendo que analices bien lo que necesitas hacer y lo traduzcas a código de la manera más simple posible. Puede usar Objetos, los cuales te ayudarán a mantener la lógica ordenada.

Lo que necesitas:

- inputs para que el usuario ingrese los valores
- botones para ejecutar las acciones
- lógica que se encargue de resolver la acción seleccionada

(importante: los inputs y botones tienen que estar dentro de 1 formulario para que puedas enviar la petición)

Una propuesta puede ser la siguiente:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mega Calc</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- tu formulario -->
<form method="POST">
    <label>val1:</label>
    <input type="text" name="val1" value="<?php echo ($_POST['val1']) ?? '';?>"> <!-- conservar el valor ingresado -->
    <label>val2:</label>
    <input type="text" name="val2" value="<?php echo ($_POST['val2']) ?? '';?>"><br>
    <button type="submit" name="operacion" value="salir">salir</button>
    <button type="submit" name="operacion" value="+">+</button>
    <button type="submit" name="operacion" value="-">-</button>
    <button type="submit" name="operacion" value="/">/</button>
    <button type="submit" name="operacion" value="*">*</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
// si presiona 1 de los botones
if ($_POST) {

    if ($_POST['operacion'] == 'salir') {
        echo 'Saliste!!'; // redireccionar o lo que quieras
        exit();
    }

    $Calculadora = new Calculadora(
        $_POST['val1'], $_POST['val2']
    );

    $Calculadora->operacion = $_POST['operacion'];
    echo $Calculadora->resolver();
}


// logica de la calculadora. Lo puedes mover a otro archivo
class Calculadora
{
    private $val1;
    private $val2;
    public $operacion;

    public function __construct($val1, $val2)
    {
        // 0 por defecto si no se define 1 valor
        // si quieres puedes pasar como 3er parametro la operacion
        $this->val1 = $val1 ?? 0;
        $this->val2 = $val2 ?? 0;
    }

    public function resolver()
    {
        switch ($this->operacion) {
            case '+':
                return $this->sumar();
                break;
            case '-':
                return $this->restar();
                break;
            case '/':
                return $this->dividir();
                break;
            case '*':
                return $this->multiplicar();
                break;
            default:
                return false; // o algun mensaje
                break;
        }
    }

    private function sumar()
    {
        return $this->val1 + $this->val2;
    }

    private function restar()
    {
        return $this->val1 - $this->val2;
    }

    private function dividir()
    {
        if ($this->val2 == 0) {
            //return 'division por 0 no permitida: imprimir 1 mensaje o lo que sea';
            return false;
        }

        return $this->val1 / $this->val2;
    }

    private function multiplicar()
    {
        return $this->val1 * $this->val2;
    }
}
```